# How to use map() for multiple lists?

Tags: list, dart, flutter

### I want to get something like this:

```
[list1, list2].map( (var1, var2) => do something with var1;
do something with var2)
```

I tried:

```
List<int> counts = [1,2,3];
List<String> strings = ['','2',''];
print([counts, strings].map((list) => list[0].isEven; list[1].lenght))
```

Comment: It's pretty unclear what the result of your map function is. Are you looking of a for-each instead of a map?

Comment: It would be like this

Comment: return Column(
      children:
      [counts, times].map(([count, timeControllers]) =>
          Container(
              child:

Comment: `.map` doesn't return a `List` but an `Iterable`. you need to do `.map(function).toList()`

Comment: Ok, but my problem is to use [list1, list2].map(...) somehow

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What is the expected result?

Comment: The result must be a list of rows where would be two variables from outside

Comment: What exactly would the result for the example in your question look like?

Comment: It can be a list. But question is how to use map for multiple lists? What is syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`IterableZip` from `package:collection` should help.

https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/collection/latest/collection/IterableZip-class.html

```
IterableZip([list1, list2]).map((values) {
    doSomethingWith(values[0]);
    doSomethingWith(values[1]);
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately the two lists have to have the same type elements for IterableZip to be useful. OP has a <String>[] and an <int>[].

Comment: That's OK for the two lists to have different elements types, it will fall back to being an `Iterable<dynamic>`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/async/latest/async/StreamZip-class.html is what you want.

First convert `list1` and `list2` into their own individual streams, and then use `StreamZip` to combine both streams.

This for example will turn both values into a stream of strings containing both values:

```
StreamZip([list1, list2]).map((valuePair) => "${valuePair[0]}, ${valuePair[1]}"));
```

Comment: There is an another Error  error: The argument type 'List<List<Object>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable<Stream>'. (argument_type_not_assignable)

Comment: You need to convert your lists to streams first. You can use `Stream.fromIterable(list)`

Comment: IterableZip is the sync equivalent of StreamZip.

Comment: I just deleted my previous as it turns out I had stated something incorrectly. @NateBosch 's answer is still the best solution here. I was unaware of IterableZip, but now that I am, it is a more appropriate way of achieving what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want the `zip` function which dart doesn't provide by default. A quick implementation would be something like this:

```
List<T3> zipList<T1, T2, T3>(List<T1> l1, List<T2> l2, T3 Function(T1, T2) zipper) {
  if (l1.isEmpty) throw ArgumentError.value(l1, "l1", "input list cannot be empty");
  if (l1.length != l2.length) throw ArgumentError("Two lists must have the same length");
  var result = List<T3>(l1.length);
  for(var i = 0; i < l1.length; i++) {
    result.add(zipper(l1[i], l2[i]));
  }
  return result;
}

// here a quick example of how to use it.
class Bar {
  final int i;
  final String s;
  Bar(this.i, this.s);

  @override
  String toString() => "Bar: $i - $s";
}

void testZipList() {
  var list1 = [1,2,3];
  var list2 = ["", "2", ""];
  var bars = zipList(list1, list2, (l1, l2) => Bar(l1, l2));
  bars.forEach(print);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the zipList provided in the accepted answer, here is a `listIterable` that may be useful if you have iterables that are not lists, yet.

```
Iterable<T3> zipIterable<T1, T2, T3>(Iterable<T1> l1, Iterable<T2> l2, T3 Function(T1, T2) zipper) sync* {
  var i1 = l1.iterator;
  var i2 = l2.iterator;
  while(true) {
    var fin1 = !i1.moveNext();
    var fin2 = !i2.moveNext();
    if (fin1 != fin2) {
      throw ArgumentError("Two iterables must have the same length");
    }
    if (fin1) {
      return;
    }
    yield zipper(i1.current, i2.current);
  }
}
```